# Solving limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 + 5n^2 + (-1)^n \cdot n}{5n^2 - 13}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Trying to solve:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 + 5n^2 + (-1)^n \cdot n}{5n^2 - 13}$$

I tried to divide with $n^3$ and $n^2$, but the limit of $(-1)^{n}$ is not existed, so i am wondering if the limit of $(-1)^{n}\cdot n$ does exist ?

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} = 0$.  This is sandwiched between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $-\frac{1}{n}$ both of which converge to zero so it does too.  Similarly for $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$

Comment: The quick and dirty explanation is that you can ignore everything except the "biggest" thing from the numerator and denominator.  The behavior of your fraction is like that of $\frac{3n^3}{5n^2}$.  This is formalized of course by doing as you suggest by dividing top and bottom in this case by $n^3$ or $n^2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz but " the biggest " thing is (-1)^n no ? because it is an logarithm  function , so the limit of the sequence is infinity ?

Comment: Absolutely not.  $(-1)^n$ is always equal to either $1$ or $-1$ for every positive integer $n$ (*we don't care about non-integer values, but even then it would have been on the unit circle*).  $(-1)^n$ is *tiny* compared to $3n^3$ which grows without bound.  Similarly, $(-1)^n\cdot n$ is also small in comparison to $3n^3$.

Comment: so the limit for the whole sequence is approaching infinity , right ? though i am still confused with the limit of $(-1)^{n}/n$

Comment: For all $n$ you have $\frac{(-1)}{n}\leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ so $0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$ so the limit of the center expression is zero as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 + 5n^2 + (-1)^n \cdot n}{5n^2 - 13} > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 + 5n^2 - n}{5n^2- 13}$$

for all $n$. Since the limit of the right hand side is $\infty$ (which you can find by dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$), the LHS (original equation) is also $\infty$.

Comment: why dividing both the numerator and denominator by $n^{2}$ ? and not dividing numerator with $n^{3}$ ( since it is the biggest ) and denominator by $n^{2}$ (since it is the biggest ) ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, and I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We have indeed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{n}\cdot n$ doesn't exist but we have that

$$ \frac{3n^3 + 5n^2 + (-1)^n \cdot n}{5n^2 - 13} =  \frac{n^3}{n^2}\cdot\frac{3 + \frac 5 n +\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} }{5- \frac{13}{n^2}}$$

and

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|= \frac{1}{n^2}\to 0 \implies  \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\to 0$$